# Form validation regex and DOM: What would be the best way to implement regex in a form validation

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, validation, dom

Form validation regex and DOM:
 What would be the best way to implement regex in a form validation?

Im currently doing this, but when I validate it's not matching the values:

```
if(this.value.length > 0 && this.value === /^[a-zA-Z]+$/ );
```

Thank You in advance!

Comment: sorry to not be concise I'm really new to javascript and stack overflow, my function checks onBlur if the form input matches the length and the characters match the regex for a first name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the `test()` method.

```
var patt = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/; //define your RegEx

    if(this.value.length > 0 && patt.test(this.value)){ //check if this.value is longer than one character AND matches your RegEx
           //do something
     };
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp

Comment: I tried using match(), but once I initiate my function, the input still fails to match the RegEx. When It's only the 
    (this.value.length > 0 ) I have success, but when I try to match I get errors.

Comment: I've updated the answer. The `test()` method will return true or false. so in this case if it matches your regex, the if condition will be true and your code should execute. My previous answer with the `match()` method was wrong because match will return a the matching value as an array, not a boolean so it won't work...

Comment: Thank you so much, your edit helped a lot! I would up your vote, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

Why you code does not mathing any values?
Because you used typewise equality test `===`. In dynamic types of JavaScript world it states for: test types of those values if they are the same and then test values if they are equal.
So when you were trying to test in that way values of some textboxes, which are strings

```
typeof('a')
```

this code will yield "string" because of 'a' is indeed a string. But:

```
typeof(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)
```

this will yield "object". As you see typewise equality test will always return false when you are trying compare string to object.

That is for testing equality of objects and its values. For regex see 'bam' answer.